# Classification Model - How to Preprocess Text

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining, data-preprocessing

I have a Dataframe that contains 2 columns:

'Skills' column - each cell contains a list of strings describing different technical and soft skills of a person, e.g: [Python,SQL,Java,Team Management,Teamwork,Communication skills]

'Status' column (target column to predict) - categorical column with 2 categories: Passed / Failed.

I would like to create a machine learning model to predict the 'Status' of a person using the list of skills as input. (Each person can have a different number of skills). I am new to the world of text classification, and I would like to know how to prepare the data for modeling. How should I handle the 'Skills' column and which libraries should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with scikit-learn, and try a naive bayes classifier:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
```

example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"skills":[["Python","SQL","Java","Team Management","Teamwork","Communication skills"],["Java"]], "status": ["Passed","Failed"]})
```

some text normalization

```
translation = {"Team Management": "Team_Management","Communication skills":"Communication_skills"}

df["skills"] = df["skills"].apply(lambda row: [translation.get(x,x) for x in row])

df["skills"] = df["skills"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))
```

vectorizer

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df["skills"])

y = df["status"]
```

model training

```
model = BernoulliNB()
model.fit(X, y)
```

inference

```
test= vectorizer.transform(["Python SQL Java Team_Management", "Java"])

model.predict(test)
```

that will return

```
array(['Passed', 'Failed'], dtype='<U6')
```